# Actionscript 3.0 Namespace is invalid in the application descriptor file

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces

I am trying to make an Android app. Everything was working fine until I  tried to implement ads. Now when I try to publish my game to my phone it gives me the error message "Error creating files. Namespace is invalid in the application descriptor file". What I have tried is changing  to  and have been looking online for quite some time with no luck as to fixing this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/20.0">
  <id>keepmoving</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.2</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel></versionLabel>
  <filename>keep moving</filename>
  <description/>





  <!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->
  <name>keep moving</name>





  <!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>keep%20moving.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon/>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
<android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
                 <application>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
                 </application>
            </manifest>
        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>  
  <extensions>
    <extensionID>so.cuo.platform.admob</extensionID>
  </extensions>
</application>
```

Comment: Ads means you are using some ANE. You probably forgot to add ANE files to your build so the packager cannot relate **android:name** entries to anything. Did you, BTW, try to google that error by its description? There are lots of results that seem relevant.

Comment: I already had the ANE file added to the build and yes I have google that specific error message before and tried mostly everything that showed up. I tried updating my AIR to the latest, the app now compiles and run but now the ads will not show. I message the original creator of the ANE I am using and am currently waiting for a responds

Comment: All you did is correct. Just to be sure, do you call the ANE initialization from your app script somewhere? Also, did you check, maybe there are more things to add to descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with Adobe Air 24. Upgrading to Adobe Air 31 fixed it for me.